# Network printer suddenly stopped working on one computer, even "Test page failed to print"

Tags: windows-xp, printer, network-printer

The network printer is working fine from the print spooler (Windows Server 2003) and other computers on the network.  It's just one XP computer that is having a problem.  The user was printing several things, then got 'an error message' and now the computer will not print, even after rebooting and doing delete/add in Printers and Faxes.

Attempting to print a test page immediately brings up a dialog saying the test page failed to print, and offers the print troubleshooter.  The troubleshooter offers no further insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the issue is coming from the end user's computer. I would check for reinstalling the driver first of all but you have to delete it completely:

> Windows XP adds a user interface feature to delete driver files so the steps for Windows 2000 and earlier are no longer necessary. To delete printer driver files in Windows XP:
>
> - Click Start, and then click Printers and Faxes.
> - On the File menu, click Server Properties.
> - On the Drivers tab, click the printer driver that you want to delete, and then click Remove.

Then, I would also check the [print spooler](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324757) as mentionned by BBlake.

Is this printer on a print server or simply network-shared?

Comment: Reinstalling drivers fixed it.

Comment: Please consider upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Might check to make sure that the windows XP print spooler service is running.  Failing that you might try [reinstalling the spooler service](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324757) for XP:

Comment: Checked that, it was.  I tried stopping on a different computer, and got a relevant error message earlier in the process.